# Javascript/canvas If else not working properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, conditional-statements, if-statement

When I click any of the 2 radio buttons the text overlaps. I want the if else conditions to run seperate. That means when I click the higher radio button, it checks if playertotal is higher than computertotal and writes the outcome. The same with the lower radio button.

[image]

This belongs to a longer code:

```
function button1()
{
    // Checks if it's the players turn
    if(playerturn==true)
    {
        // Generates eyes for the dice
        var eyes3=Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+ 1;
        var eyes4=Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+ 1;
        //Shows the eyes
        showEyes(eyes3, 325);
        showEyes(eyes4, 450);

        computerturn=true;
        playerturn=false;

        playerTotal = eyes3+eyes4;
        //Checks if player has won
        if (higher=1 && playerTotal > computerTotal) 
        {
            pen.font = '20pt Calibri';
            pen.fillText('You have won',300,250);
        }
        else if (higher=1 && playerTotal < computerTotal) 
        {
            pen.font = '20pt Calibri';
            pen.fillText('You have lost',300,250);
        }

        if (lower=1 && playerTotal < computerTotal) 
        {
            pen.font = '20pt Calibri';
            pen.fillText('You have won!',300,250);
        }
        else if (lower=1 && playerTotal > computerTotal) 
        {
            pen.font = '20pt Calibri';
            pen.fillText('You have lost',300,250);
        }
    }
}

function higherRadioButton()
{
    higher = 1
    lower = 0
}

function lowerRadioButton()
{
    lower = 1
    higher = 0
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, the comparison operator is `==`, not `=`. Your code should look like this:

```
if (higher == 1 && playerTotal > computerTotal) 
{
    //...
}
```

And same for all other statements.

To avoid future problems of this sort, always put the number to the left:

```
if (1 == higher && playerTotal > computerTotal) 
{
    //...
}
```

This way if you forget one "=" you will get error instead of wrong results.

Comment: Thanks alot, this fixed it. I'm new to javascript so I haven't thought of it.